# PowerShell " Parameter set cannot be resolved" When Calling Other Script

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm struggling to call a second script in one of my PowerShell scripts at the moment using Invoke-Expression. It's currently producing an error:

"Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Annoyingly, it works fine for one switch (being -ServerDriveReport), but doesn't work for the other.

The first script (called DriveReport.ps1) is like:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ServerDriveReport")]
    [switch]$ServerDriveReport,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="VMDriveReport")]
    [switch]$VMDriveReport)

If($ServerDriveReport){
Invoke-Expression "& 'C:\Scripts\Drive Report\EmailDriveReport.ps1' -ServerDriveReport"}

If($VMDriveReport){
Invoke-Expression "& 'C:\Scripts\Drive Report\EmailDriveReport.ps1' -VMDriveReport"}
```

The "EmailDriveReport.ps1" script is like:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ServerDriveReport")]
    [switch]$ServerDriveReport,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="VMDriveReport")]
    [switch]$VMDriveReport)

If($ServerDriveReport){
# Send an email containing the server drive report}

If($VMDriveReport){
# Send an email contining the VM drive report}
```

When running "DriveReport.ps1 -ServerDriveReport" everything works as expected. But when running "DriveReport.ps1 -VMDriveReport", that's when I get the aforementioned error message.

Has anyone seen this before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Without attempting to solve your immediate problem (which is not obvious to me from the code posted), consider using the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable via [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to pass the parameters through to the 2nd script:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ServerDriveReport")]
    [switch]$ServerDriveReport,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="VMDriveReport")]
    [switch]$VMDriveReport)
)

& 'C:\Scripts\Drive Report\EmailDriveReport.ps1' @PSBoundParameters
```

Generally, `Invoke-Expression` should be avoided, because there are usually more robust solutions available and because it presents a security risk if invoked on untrusted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! 
I managed to resolve this by carefully going over the script and finding out one of the Else statements was calling the file incorrectly. I've now changing this to:
& 'C:\Scripts\Drive Report\EmailDriveReport.ps1' as suggested.